# Why Saab -90 loses suddenly all its power on 120 km/h but gains it back after restart?

Tags: power, intermittent-problems, saab, motors

I was driving uphill on the motorway, when the Saab lost all its power suddenly. I parked, restarted the machine, and the car worked again.

I have rented the car. If anything happens to the car, etc left next to the motorway, I have to pay 2000 euros. I am thinking what is the risk of driving the car after such an incident.

Answer (score 1):

I had a vehicle ( 1998 GMC ) that had the same symptoms . It was the battery connection . It was clean and tight but needed to be rotated a quarter turn to mesh the 2 cable connectors on the battery post. Once I found it , it was a one minute repair.